# switchIfEmpty in Reactor java is not executing

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm new with Reactor on java and I experience a problem with switchIfEmpty.

My objective is to check an id if valid to perform a findById from a cache variable, and if not exist, i get data from the db repository to update cache variable and perfom some operations. check the code below.

**My problem** is that when we get Mono.empty, the code inside **switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(()) is never executed** in run time (in the **two calls of switchIfEmpty in the code below**) but it is working in a UT test

```
// Verification of the cache
    Mono<Param> ParamMono = Optional.ofNullable(data.get(id)).map(Mono::just).orElseGet(Mono::empty);
    return ParamMono.flatMap(item -> {
        return this.updateParamDB(item, nouveauLibelle);
    })
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
        // Vérification de la BD si élement non existant en cache.
        return paramRepository.findById(id).flatMap(item ->{
            this.updateParamDB(item, nouveauLibelle);
            return Mono.just(Param).subscribeOn(scheduler);
        })
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(()->{
            // Création de l'objet en si non existant.
            if(StringUtils.isNoneBlank(nouveauLibelle)){
                data.put(id, Param);
                return paramRepository.save(Param);
            }
        return Mono.just(Param).subscribeOn(scheduler);

        }));
    }));
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Do you mean first `switchIfEmpty` or second?

Comment: The two switchIfEmpty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if there is a subscriber for your flow, you can use both implicit and explicit approaches. Explicitly, you can check by using the subscribe method, while implicitly, you can utilize flatMap/map. It's important to note that invoking onNext alone will not affect the flow or establish a subscription.

Comment: Thank for your reponse, it was exactly what i did. I called onNext on the flow instead of flatMap.
Thank you